# Gremlin query to check for two properties value

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, graph-query

I am trying to do a query in Gremlin similar to the following.

`SELECT * FROM profiles WHERE firstName like 'John' OR lastName like 'John'`

both firstName and lastName are properties of one vertex

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `profiles` is a node label (akin to a table name in SQL), and that the column names are properties on a node, the simple Gremlin form (without `like`) would be something like:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('profile').
  or(has('firstName','John'),has('lastName','John'))
```

However, the Gremlin language (before release 3.6) did not have a way to express anything along the lines of `like`. Some implementations offer language extensions or integration with an external index such as Elastic Search or Open Search. In those cases that is a way to achieve the `like` functionality.

Starting with TinkerPop 3.6 a new `regex` text predicate has been added. So the query above can be re-written using any supported regular expression. For example, a simple case where you are not sure if the name is capitalized might be queried using:

```java
g.V().hasLabel('profile').
  or(has('firstName',regex('[J|j]ohn')),has('lastName',regex('[J|j]ohn')))
```

It may take a while before implementations move up to this new level, but once they do, this is one way to address queries that need vaguer searches.